# GWT framework for iphone

Tags: iphone, gwt, frameworks

i know Java,not Objective-c but like to program IPHONE and IPAD.
now i need to use some sort of framework directly for device communication and function 
communication(http connection API,barcode reader API,remote file access API,twitter API)
is there any framework that is written in Java using GWT.

i saw phoneGAP.but like GWT.

i like GWT but like some sort of framework(Device API + Function API) on top of GWT.

is there any suggestion?

Comment: @user153506 please go through your questions and mark them as answered, where people took time to provide you with free help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use PhoneGap? I've used it for a GWT based application and it works great. You just need to wrap the PhoneGap API that you need in a JSNI call, but otherwise it works great.

Answer (score 5):

GWT is a Java-based framework. GWT or wrappers around GWT will not work on the iPhone or iPad, because native app development for those platforms requires writing code in C, Objective C or C++.

As a service to your fellow Stack Overflow users and for people who search old questions on Stack Overflow, please mark some of your previous questions as answered, where people took the time to give you correct or useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a native iphone/ipad app using GWT (except perhaps through PhoneGap), but you can create a web page using GWT which will run on a server.  The iphone/ipad can then access the app using it's browser.  With HTML 5, you can do some advanced things such as access the GPS store data in a local database etc.